# Wordpress: Navigation Border-Bottom

Tags: css, wordpress

I am working on this [website](http://ergon.nowcommu.myhostpoint.ch/home/) and I am trying to delete the `border-bottom` in the navigation for the last 2 right navigation points "DE" and "FR". I have tried this via CSS, without results:

```
#menu-item-394 { border-right: 1px solid #EEE; border-bottom: none !important; }

#menu-item-393 { border-left: 1px solid #EEE; border-bottom: none !important; }
```

Any Tips?

Comment: I saw it's working now. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

border-bottom is applied on anchor attribute.
try this css.

```
#menu-item-393 a, #menu-item-394 a  {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The `border-bottom` rule is declared on the `a` elements. Your CSS should look like this:

```
#menu-item-393 a, #menu-item-394 a {
    border-bottom: 0px;
}
```

You shouldn't need to add the `!important` decalration.